# JSON POST request - receiving JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, post

In my .html file I have the following code:

```
    var country = {
        "c_3" : {
            "name" : countryName,
            "population" : countryPop,
            "language" : countryLang
            }
        };

    var data = JSON.stringify(country);

    $.post('http://127.0.0.1:8090/admin/addCountry', data, function(data){},'json')     
    };
```

Then in my .js server I have:

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 8090;
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post('/admin/addCountry', function (req, res){
    var countryName = req.body.c_3.name;
    var countryPop = req.body.c_3.population;
    var countryLang = req.body.c_3.language;


    var newCountry = {
        "c_3" : {
            "name" : countryName,
            "population" : countryPop,
            "lauguage" : countryLang
        }
    }

    fs.readFile("/countries.json", 'utf8', function (err, data){
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        data["c_3"] = newCountry["c_3"];
        console.log(data);
        res.end(JSON.stringify(data));
    });

});
```

But using console.log() I can identify that in the .js the variables countryName, countryPop, etc. are undefined. But I'm struggling to work out why. Any help would be much appreciated - thank you!

Comment: I think you have to required fs before use it in your js server file var fs=require('fs');

Comment: Sorry, I have that too - just missed off the extract I put up, I'll modify code